# Apply task not working with mapper

Tags: ant

I am banging my head on the walls with ant...

My target is the following:

```
<target name="js.minify">
    <apply executable="java">
        <arg line="-jar"></arg>
        <arg path="path_to_file/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"></arg>
        <arg line="-v"></arg>
        <srcfile></srcfile>
        <arg line="-o"></arg>
        <targetfile></targetfile>

        <globmapper from="*.js" to="*.min.js" casesensitive="no"/>
        <fileset id="jsFiles" dir="${artifactsdir}/js">
        </fileset>
    </apply>
</target>
```

Here's the funny thing, with the mapper in the code nothing gets processed. I can even change the name of the executable to some non existing application and it won't complain, ie it skips the apply. If I remove the mapper and the target file, at least I get some error message. If I try another process with just the source file, it runs. I really narrowed it down to mapper which seems to select the files only if they have changed (?!), ie if I edit them and save them, it works... any idea how to force mapper to take any files, even non modified (whatever that means) files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to ignore the timestamp checking you get when you use `<targetfile>`.
You can do that using the `force="true"` parameter of the [`<apply>` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html). (It's at the bottom of the list of parameters, note that this option was new at Ant version 1.6.3.)

```
<apply executable="java" force="true">
    ...
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much! that did the trick indeed. For some reason I focused on the mapper when the solution was on apply...